Bound norm 2 of semipositive definite with frobenius norm of matrix function
Suppose I have a positive semidefinite matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ defined as
$$
S = APA^T
$$
where $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
Given the matrix norm 2 of $S$ I am able to derive a bound of the form
$$
\left\lVert S \right\rVert_2 \leq \left\lVert A \sqrt P \right\rVert_F^2
$$
For few reasons I am trying to get a bound of the form. However I was hoping to find a bound of the form
$$
\left\lVert S \right\rVert_2 \leq \left\lVert A \sqrt{P} \right\rVert_F
$$
which is not true. Now however I am trying to find a function $f$  such that
$$
\left\lVert S \right\rVert_2 \leq \left\lVert A f(P) \right\rVert_F
$$
Is there some hopefully simple $f$ for which such bound holds?

No such $f$ exists. E.g. when $P=I$ and $A=kI$, we have
$$
\|S\|_2=\|k^2I\|_2=k^2>k\|f(I)\|_F=\|Af(P)\|_F
$$
when $k>0$ is sufficiently large.
